# content width not working in print screen

Tags: html, css, printing, angular7, printscreen

I am trying to print the receipt page below. It looks like as below in the browser. The content in the middle(with white background) has fixed width and is centered. I am using angular 7 and bootstrap 4

[image]

When i try to print it from my code using window.print() , the width of the content doesn't show correctly. The content which is in the white background takes full width of the page when in print mode. Below is how it shows in the print preview in chrome.
I want the print preview to be similar as it was in the browser.

[image: print preview]

Below are the scss i am using

1. For the grey background

   ```
     .background {
          height:100%;
          width: 100%;
          background-color: #E9E8EA; //Grey
          margin: 0px;
          padding: 0px;  
     }
   ```
2. For the receipt content in the middle

   ```
      .content {    
            height: 85.33%; 
            width: 35.95%; 
            border-radius: 5px;
            background-color: #FFFFFF; //white  
            padding-top: 1.47%;
            padding-bottom: 2.21%;    
        }
   ```

I would really appreciate if someone gives me idea on this.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `@page` or `@media print` in your css.

https://www.sitepoint.com/css-printer-friendly-pages/

Comment: I tried by enclosing all my css inside `@media print{ ...}` and no luck. It didn't work with `@page` also.

Comment: You may have duplicate classes in your css. Try `!important`